# Any non-commercial certificate authority issuer for web applications?

Tags: web-application, tls, certificate-authority

Is there any non-commercial certificate authority capable of issuing valid certificates for web applications? I mean, the certificate must be accepted by browsers, like those of commercial CAs?

Comment: Basically dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/where-to-get-an-ssl-certificate-for-personal-website and (later) https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18919/are-there-technical-disadvantages-in-using-free-ssl-certificates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Start SSL](http://www.startssl.com/) is a commercial CA that issues standard SSL certificates free of charge. They are accepted by all common browsers, except for very old versions of Opera.

Comment: UPDATE: StartSSL/Startcom was sold to WoSign who were caught cheating in 2016 and over the next year or so distrusted by everybody; see the dupes I added to the Q and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127575/is-startssl-com-a-trustworthy-site

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Let's Encrypt.](https://letsencrypt.org/) Is a free, automated, and open certificate authority brought to you by the Internet Security Research Group ([ISRG](https://www.abetterinternet.org/)) and sponsored by several companies.