# Is StartSSL.com a trustworthy site?

Tags: certificate-authority

I just got the following email:

> Dear StartCom customers,
>
> This electronic mail message was created by StartCom's Administration
>   Personnel:
>
> StartCom, a leading global Certificate Authority (CA) and provider of
>   trusted identity and authentication services, announces a new service
>   – StartEncrypt today, an automatic SSL certificate issuance and
>   installation software for your web server.
>
> StartEncrypt is based the StartAPI system to let you get SSL
>   certificate and install the SSL certificate in your web server for
>   free and automatically, no any coding, just one click to install it in
>   your server.
>
> Compare with Let’s Encrypt, StartEncrypt support Windows and Linux
>   server for most popular web server software, and have many
>   incomparable advantages as:
>
> (1) Not just get the SSL certificate automatically, but install it
>   automatically;
>
> (2) Not just Encrypted, but also identity validated to display EV
>   Green Bar and OV organization name in the certificate;
>
> (3) Not just 90 days period certificate, but up to 39 months, more
>   than 1180 days;
>
> (4) Not just low assurance DV SSL certificate, but also high assurance
>   OV SSL certificate and green bar EV SSL certificate;
>
> (5) Not just for one domain, but up to 120 domains with wildcard
>   support;
>
> (6) All OV SSL certificate and EV SSL certificate are free, just make
>   sure your StartSSL account is verified as Class 3 or Class 4 identity.
>
> StartEncrypt together with StartSSL to let your website start to https
>   without any pain, to let your website keep green bar that give more
>   confident to your online customer and bring to online revenue to you.
>   Let’s start to encrypt now.
>
> Please do not reply to this email. This is an unmonitored email
>   address, and replies to this email cannot be responded to or read. If
>   you have any question or comments, just click Here to send your question to us, thanks.
>
> Best Regards StartCom™ Certification Authority

There are several sketchy-sounding phrases, like `and have many incomparable advantages as:`

I did glance at the startssl.com website, and it didn't exactly inspire confidence, other than it had the green bar in the URL for StartCom Ltd.:

[image: startssl]

Is this a trustworthy CA that just happens to have poor English copywriters, or is there some kind of history that one should be worried about?

Comment: I don't quite understand... The email starts with `Dear StartCom customers,` so shouldn't you know better if they are trustworthy?

Comment: When looking at generating certificates, it is also important to ask how easy it is to *revoke* them. If for some reason a certificate is compromised, it needs be revoked *now* (not in 3 months, and not for an exorbitant fee). Crucially, this is not mentioned in the advantages of StartEncrypt... so be sure to check.

Comment: Even if not for the outdated website design, I might be careful of StartSSL security based on [this](http://www.securityweek.com/startssl-flaw-allowed-attackers-obtain-ssl-cert-any-domain), [this](https://raim.codingfarm.de/blog/2014/04/12/distrusting-startssl/) and [other issues](https://www.google.com/search?q=startssl+security).

Comment: @SumanSrinivasan, they ended up offering free revocation for Class 1 cert users for Heartbleed... that second "this" was only briefly true.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome no longer trust certificates issued by StartSSL:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/startssl-certificate-gives-sec-error-revoked-certificate-in-firefox-and-err-cert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**StartCom was very well legitimate** while they still operated, but are nowadays not trusted anymore by browsers. As of early 2018, they are [completely defunct](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mozilla.dev.security.policy/LM1SpKHJ-oc/4nBsP1xJAQAJ) and have stopped issuing certificates.

At the time when the question was asked, StartSSL/StartCOM was a Certificate Authority as any other. My original answer explaining this in detail is shown below.

However, @Jacob C [noticed me](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127575/is-startssl-com-a-trustworthy-site/127580?noredirect=1#comment328012_127580), that StartCom is not trusted by browsers anymore, nowadays.

The simple reason was that they (which is: StartCom and WoSign, which were the same company) [violated several requirements of CAs and misissued invalid/rogue certificates](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:WoSign_Issues), so mayor browser vendors [distrusted](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/) [these certificates](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html) in 2016.

As of the end of 2017 they seem [to operate again](https://www.startcomca.com/) under a different domain. They still tried to get included in Firefox, etc. again.

**Another update:** Later StartCom announced to give up. A Cure53 audit was required to get back into the root store, but [Cure53 said](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.security.policy/hNOJJrN6WfE), the audited PHP "was full of holes, poorly commented, had few or no tests, and showed every evidence of being hacked together in an enormous rush". It  "was frankly a security disaster."

They'll stop business at 2018-01-01.

---

**Outdated answer:**

**Yes, StartSSL belongs to a StartCom - a legitimate certificate authority**

Here some points how one can notice it is a legitimate site:

- They use an [EV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) certificate.
- As they are a CA they of course signed the EV certificate by theirself and as the HTTPS connection succeeded you also know your browser trusts that CA.
- They have a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom)
- There is also some evidence on Twitter about [this CA (with its bad English-skills](https://twitter.com/hanno/status/743345398605983744)) and the [message](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/744148354809102336)...
  And you can also find a lot of guides for free certificates which describe how to get and install StartSSL certs.
- You may also [search a snippet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=StartEncrypt+is+based+the+StartAPI+system+to+let+you+get+SSL+certificate+and+install+the+SSL+certificate+in+your+web+server+for+free+and+automatically) of the mail.

FYI: AFAIK this mail was only send to customers who registered at StartSSL, so you certainly used their service at least once - or at least registered there. I doubt that they would send spam mails to random addresses.

BTW: Their web interface has been much uglier recently. They already had been improving it.

Comment: In 2017, StartCom is NOT considered trustworthy anymore by Google, Mozilla, etc. see: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/07/07/google_ban_hammer_drops_on_wosign_startcom_in_two_months/ / https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2017/04/05/ssl-labs-distrusts-wosign-and-startcom-certificates / http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/09/27/mozilla_wants_woeful_wosign_certs_off_the_list/

Comment: @JacobC. And in 2018, they are completely defunct!

Answer (score 15):

[This answer was true in June 2016.  It is not in $NOW; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom).]

---

**Yes, [StartCom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom) is a legitimate Certificate Authority.**

On the plus side, they were at one time the only provider which would hand out *free* SSL certificates *which were recognized by the major browsers*.  (There's competition now in [Let's Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt)).

On the minus side, their web site design and implementation is clunky, non-intuitive, and lacks pretty.

(The [danconnor](https://danconnor.com/posts/50f65364a0fd5fd1f7000001/avoid_startcom_startssl_like_the_plague_) link @ZN13 provided appears to be someone wanted more pretty and didn't expect rigidity out of the CA process...........

............you should expect rigidity out of the CA process.)

Comment: I've used StartSSL.com in the past and can confirm they are a legitimate Certificate Authority. Their user interface has a (very) dated look and feel, but it works easy enough and they deliver what they promise.

Comment: @Jacco They actually updated the site design recently. It now feels like any other modern site.

Comment: If anything that link by ZN13 makes StartSSL look particularly trustworthy and responsible. Any CA that would've given the blog author an EV certificate with the information provided, should be banned (sadly that'd be most I'm afraid).

Comment: They changed their process since that blog post was made. My last renewal didn't ask for a phone bill or send me anything by mail. Instead they asked for a photo of myself holding, or at least in the picture with, one of my identification documents.

Comment: I used StartSSL for several years & had no problem. Then Let's Encrypt appeared & shaked the market. Last week I got an email about a letsencrypt-alike methodology from StarCom. They made extended verification certs free (IIRC) & published a cli tool to auto-install & configure the cert on your server - I didn't test it. Anyway, I support everything that @gowenfawr wrote, but would add an extra consideration: Until recently, you needed to pay StartSSL a fee to revoke a certificate - don't know if still applies. Besides that you couldn't renew a free cert if did not expire yet! That's terrible!

Comment: @jweyrich I haven't ever had a problem getting a new certificate for my domains the week or so before the existing one ended.

Comment: @ArtMcBain: I got a message saying the certificate for the domain I was trying to renew (or issue) did already exist at Class 1 level (IIRC, it was back in 2012). Couldn't get past this & didn't want to pay the revoke fee, so I waited the 2 weeks or so, and issued it again (caused some downtime) - but I didn't take it further nor asked for any support, so it could have been entirely my fault - the fact is that independently, it was quite non-intuitive to me at the time I needed it. Did it work right away for you renewing 1-or-2 weeks before the expiring date?

Comment: @jweyrich It did. However I had a Class 2 certificate, not a Class 1, so they may allow you to issue a new certificate before expiration at that level.

Comment: @ArtMcBain that's probably one of the differences. Class 2 is (or at least was) not free, while Class 1 is free, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41418/discussion-between-art-mcbain-and-jweyrich).

Comment: Read @Suman Srinivasan's comment.